# How to automatically insert user id in relation table(laravel)?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I had staffs table and keluargas table. Each staff will have many keluargas.

I want to add a new member to a specific staff by filling up the details(nama, kp, alamat, hubungan, tel, status)

in keluargas table, there are id, staff_id, nama, kp, tel, alamat, satuts, hubungan fields..

the problem when I want to insert the new row with value to keluargas, it gives error as the staff_id has no value. How to take the staff_id value of the staff to be inserted in keluargas table?

This is the code to insert new data in keluargas.

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{


     $keluarga = [
    'nama' => $request->nama,
    'kp' => $request->kp,
    'tel' => $request->tel,
    'pekerjaan' => $request->pekerjaan,
    'alamat' => $request->alamat,
    'hubungan' => $request->hubungan,
    'status_kahwin' => $request->status_kahwin,
    'status_undi' => $request->status_undii,
];

$save = keluargas::insert($keluarga);

if($save)
    return redirect('keluarga');
else
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

the data to be displayed is from this code:

```
   public function index()
{
     if (Auth::user()->type == 0) {

        $section = Auth::user()->section;

        $data['data'] = DB::table('staffs')
                        ->join('keluargas', 'staffs.id', '=', 'keluargas.staff_id')
                        ->join('kahwin', 'keluargas.status_kahwin', '=', 'kahwin.KahwinId')
                        ->join('undi', 'keluargas.status_undi', '=', 'undi.id')
                        ->where('section','=', $section)
                        ->get();


        $counter = 1;

           if(count($data) > 0)
             {
                return view('keluarga.index', $data);
             }

             else
             {
                return view('keluarga.index', $data);
             }

        //return view('home');

    } else {

        $data['data'] = DB::table('staffs')
                        ->join('keluargas', 'staffs.id', '=', 'keluargas.staff_id')
                        ->join('kahwin', 'keluargas.status_kahwin', '=', 'kahwin.KahwinId')
                        ->join('undi', 'keluargas.status_undi', '=', 'undi.id')
                        ->get();

        return view('keluarga.index', $data);
  }
}
```

this function is using resource controller in laravel.

How to add staff_id which refer to the selected staff to be add in this function?

Controller to load the form:

```
 public function create()
{
     return view('keluarga.add_keluarga');

}
```

Controller to add into db:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{


     $keluarga = [
    'nama' => $request->nama,
    'kp' => $request->kp,
    'staff_id' => $request->$id,
    'tel' => $request->tel,
    'pekerjaan' => $request->pekerjaan,
    'alamat' => $request->alamat,
    'hubungan' => $request->hubungan,
    'status_kahwin' => $request->status_kahwin,
    'status_undi' => $request->status_undii,
];

$save = keluargas::insert($keluarga);

if($save)
    return redirect('keluarga');
else
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

form fill in keluarga data:

```
   @extends('layouts.appmenu')

  @section('content')
```

```
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Tajuk Kakitangan -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="active">
                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Ahli Keluarga Baru
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>

          {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'KeluargaController@store']) !!}

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1"> 
                    {{ Form::label('nama', 'Nama') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8"> 
                    {{ Form::text('nama', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                <!-- {{ Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title']) }} -->
                </div>
            </div>

          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    {{ Form::label('no_kp', 'No K/P') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::text('kp', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    {{ Form::label('pekerjaan', 'Pekerjaan') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::text('pekerjaan', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    {{ Form::label('tel', 'No Tel') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::text('tel', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1">
                {{ Form::label('hubungan', 'Hubungan') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                {{ Form::textarea('hubungan', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    {{ Form::label('alamat', 'Alamat') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::textarea('alamat', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1">
                {{ Form::label('status', 'Status') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                {{ Form::text('status_kahwin', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1">
                {{ Form::label('status_undi', 'Status Daftar Mengundi') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                {{ Form::text('status_undi', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <form action="{{ $id }}" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">    



        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

                {{ Form::submit('Add New', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

            {!! Form::close() !!}

            {!! link_to(URL::previous(),'Cancel', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) !!}

            </div>
        </div>



</div>





 @endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing variable `staff_id`.

```
 public function create()
{
     $staffs = Staff::all();
     return view('keluarga.add_keluarga', compact('staffs'));

}
```

And:

```
 <div class="container">
            <!-- Tajuk Kakitangan -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="active">
                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Ahli Keluarga Baru
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>

          {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'KeluargaController@store']) !!}

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1"> 
                    {{ Form::label('staff', 'Staff') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <select name="staff_id">
                        @foreach($staffs as $staff)
                            <option value="{{$staff->staff_id}}">{{$staff->staff_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    {{ Form::text('nama', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}

                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1"> 
                    {{ Form::label('nama', 'Nama') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8"> 
                    {{ Form::text('nama', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                <!-- {{ Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title']) }} -->
                </div>
            </div>

          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    {{ Form::label('no_kp', 'No K/P') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::text('kp', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    {{ Form::label('pekerjaan', 'Pekerjaan') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::text('pekerjaan', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    {{ Form::label('tel', 'No Tel') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::text('tel', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1">
                {{ Form::label('hubungan', 'Hubungan') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                {{ Form::textarea('hubungan', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    {{ Form::label('alamat', 'Alamat') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::textarea('alamat', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1">
                {{ Form::label('status', 'Status') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                {{ Form::text('status_kahwin', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1">
                {{ Form::label('status_undi', 'Status Daftar Mengundi') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                {{ Form::text('status_undi', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <form action="{{ $id }}" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">    



        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

                {{ Form::submit('Add New', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

            {!! Form::close() !!}

            {!! link_to(URL::previous(),'Cancel', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) !!}

            </div>
        </div>



</div>





 @endsection
```

`$staff->staff_id, $staff->staff_name` you should changed follow your staff table.

Comment: thank you for your help. it works and the data can be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function create(Staff $staff)
{
     $data['staff'] = $staff->pluck('name','id');
     return view('keluarga.add_keluarga',$data);

}
```

in your form
Staff

```
{{ Form::select('staff_id', $staff,null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Now in store method u can use `$request->staff_id`

this should solve your problem now

Comment: how to send staff_id from url or hidden form?

Comment: show the form, from where you fill keluarga  data and controller that loads the same form